# how to store values of php variable into javascript it might be a duplicate one but here it is a different scenario

Tags: javascript, php

```
$lat=$row['lat'];
 $longitude=$row['longitude']; 


<script> center: {lat: 17.4399, longitude: 78.4983} </script>
```

Now i want to store $lat and $longitude values in the place of 
lat and longitude in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var Latitude = '<?php echo $row['lat'] ?>';
    var Longitude = '<?php echo $row['lng'] ?>'; 
    var uluru = {lat: 17.4399, lng: 78.4983};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng( Latitude,Longitude),
        map: map
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for your problem

```
<script>
        function map() {
            var Latitude = '<?php echo $row['Latitude'] ?>';
            var Longitude = '<?php echo $row['Longitude'] ?>';
            var point = {lat: Latitude, lang: Longitude};
            var u = {lat: 17.4399, lang: 78.4983};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12, center: uluru});
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: hyderbad, map: map});
        }
    </script>
```

first you need to assign value in javascript script something like that

```
var yourvalue = '<?php echo $phpvalue?>';
```

// it is support so then you can use this javascript in your code

```
<script>
    var lat_value = "<?=$lat"?>;
    var long_value = "<?=$longitude"?>;
    center: {lat: lat_value, longitude: long_value} ;
    </script>
```

this is demo code for your check

```
<?php
//somewhere set a value
$php_value = "test_value";
?>
```

then you need to assign it

```
<script>
        // using echo then assign to a js variable
        var js_value = '<?php echo $php_value ;?>';
        // then
        alert(js_value);
        </script>
```

Comment: Hello Shafiqul thanks for your replay, even i tried this it's not working

Comment: function map() {
        var Latitude = '<?php echo $row['Latitude'] ?>';
        var Longitude = '<?php echo $row['Longitude'] ?>';
        var Latitude = "<?=Latitude?>";
        var Longitude = "<?=Longitude?>";
        var hyderbad = {lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude};
        var uluru = {lat: 17.4399, lng: 78.4983};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: hyderbad,
            map: map
        });
    }

Comment: var Latitude = '<?php echo $row['irfLatitude'] ?>';
        var Longitude = '<?php echo $row['irfLongitude'] ?>';
        var point = {lat: Latitude, lang: Longitude};
        var uluru = {lat: 17.4399, lng: 78.4983};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map
        });

Comment: <script>
    var Latitude = '<?php echo $row['irfLatitude'] ?>';
    var Longitude = '<?php echo $row['irfLongitude'] ?>';
    alert(Latitude+'=='+Longitude);
    var point = {lat: Latitude, lang: Longitude};
    var uluru = {lat: 17.4399, lng: 78.4983};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12, center: uluru});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});
</script>

Comment: <script>
    var Latitude = 121;
    var Longitude = 111;
    alert(Latitude+'=='+Longitude);
    var point = {lat: Latitude, lang: Longitude};
    alert(point.lat)
    var uluru = {lat: 17.4399, lng: 78.4983};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 12, center: uluru});
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map});
</script>

Comment: ya for alert its working, but for maps it's not working. might be it's not fetching data from php is there any other way.

Comment: so check your php value first , if php value show correct then i think will work

Comment: then your google api problem i think cuz you get php value correct so

Comment: you saw php value give right so i think it is other problem, you main issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
var lat = '<?php echo $row['lat'] ?>';
var longitude = '<?php echo $row['longitude'] ?>';
</script>
```

Now you can use `lat`, `longitude` in any where in the same page like:

```
center: {lat: lat, longitude: longitude };
```

Comment: Any more , still i am looking for solution?

Comment: It's Solved. I provided working code in the comment, thank you.